# Filenet API stalling from Peoplesoft

Tags: java, peoplesoft, filenet

We just installed new version of Peoplesoft. The Java version went from 1.8 to Java 11.
The Java Filenet P8 API was working on the server, but it stalling at the createSubject. Nothing is showing on the Filenet P8 side. We can't find anything on the PS side. Certs have been updated and the sercurity in the cert is available in Java 11.
I can run this from my machine and local Linux machine.
Any ideas to why it would be stalling?

this.con = com.filenet.api.core.Factory.Connection.getConnection("https://hostname:port/wsi/FNCEWS40MTOM/");
Subject localSubject = com.filenet.api.util.UserContext.createSubject(this.con, login, password, FileNetP8WSI);

thanks,
Matt

I created a local Java API on my machine, and I have no problem connecting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: str1 = "user";
  str2 = "password";
  str3 = "FileNetP8WSI";
  str4 = "https://hostnameport/wsi/FNCEWS40MTOM/";
           
    this.con = com.filenet.api.core.Factory.Connection.getConnection(str4);
            
           Subject localSubject = com.filenet.api.util.UserContext.createSubject(this.con, str1, str2, str3);

Comment: I am stuck at UserContect.createSubject